# mirc treebar script firing off a set invaild parameters randomly

Tags: mirc

Below is the script I use for my treebar in my mirc client it fires of in the status window */set:invalid parameters not sure which set it is and most fixes I've tried including check for mismatched () or [] just cause other errors. Any help finding where the invalid parameters are would be appreciated.

```
;--[Startup event]
on *:START: { startsektor }
;--[Aliases]--
alias startsektor { switch }

;--[switchbar]
alias switch {
  if ($dialog(switchbar)) { dialog -x switchbar }
  dialog -m switchbar switchbar
}
dialog switchbar {
  title "switchbar"
  size -1 -1 135 445
  option pixels
}
on *:dialog:switchbar:init:*: {
  dcx Mark $dname DCX_Switch
  xdialog -q $dname +r cross
  xdialog -c $dname 1 treeview 0 0 135 839 showsel hasbuttons haslines
  xdid -i $dname 1 +b $color(1)
  xdid -i $dname 1 +l $color(0)
  xdid -f $dname 1 +ab ansi 8 ariel
  .timer 1 0 xdock -m $dialog($dname).hwnd +l
  .timer 1 0 iSwitch
}
alias -l xSwitch {
  if (%New. [ $+ [ $+($scon($1),$active) ] ] == On) { xdid -j switchbar 1 $xdid(switchbar,1,$+($chr(9),$2,$chr(9)),$1).find -1 7 }
  else { xdid -v switchbar 1 $xdid(switchbar,1,$+($chr(9),$2,$chr(9)),$1).find $chr(9) $2 }
}
alias -l eSwitch {
  if ($scon($1).server) { xdid -v switchbar 1 $xdid(switchbar,1,$+($chr(9),*,$chr(9)),W,$calc($1 + 1)).find $chr(9) $scon($1).server }
  elseif (!$scon($1).server) { xdid -v switchbar 1 $xdid(switchbar,1,$+($chr(9),*,$chr(9)),W,$calc($1 + 1)).find $chr(9) (Not Connected) }
}
alias iSwitch {
  xdid -r switchbar 1
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/10.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/22.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/adminprotection.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/userlist2.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/star.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/10.ico
  xdid -w switchbar 1 +n 0 icons/star.ico
  var %scid = 1
  while (%scid <= $scon(0)) {
    scon %scid
    if (!$server) { xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid $chr(9) +ceb 3 3 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) [Not Connected] $chr(9) This server is NOT connected. }
    elseif ($server) { xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid $chr(9) +ceb 2 2 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) $server $chr(9) Server - $server $chr(124) Connected at - $time(ddd hh:nn:ss tt)
      xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 1 $chr(9) +ce 1 1 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) Channels ( $+ $chan(0) $+ )
      var %c = 1
      while (%c <= $chan(0)) {
        xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 1 -1 $chr(9) +ce $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan(%c)) ] ],6 6,5 5) 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan(%c)) ] ] == On,$+($chr(40),$chan(%c),$chr(41)),$chan(%c)) $chr(9) $chan(%c) - $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan(%c)) ] ] == On,New Message,No new messages)
        inc %c
      }
      xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 2 $chr(9) +ce 4 4 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) Query ( $+ $query(0) $+ )
      var %q = 1
      while (%q <= $query(0)) {
        xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 2 -1 $chr(9) +ce $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$query(%q)) ] ],4 4,1 1) 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$query(%q)) ] ] == On,$+($chr(40),$query(%q),$chr(41)),$query(%q)) $chr(9) $query(%q) - $iif(%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$query(%q)) ] ] == On,New Message,No new messages)
        inc %q
      }
    }
    inc %scid
  }
  xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 3 $chr(9) +ceb 5 5 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) Windows ( $+ $window(0) $+ )
  var %win = $window(0)
  var %w = 1
  while (%w <= %win) {
    xdid -a switchbar 1 %scid 3 -1 $chr(9) +ce 5 5 0 0 0 $color(0) $color(0) $window(%w)
    inc %w
  }
}    
on *:ACTIVE:*: { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$active) ] ] Off | iSwitch }
on *:TEXT:*:#: {
  if ($active == $chan) { halt }
  elseif (%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] !== On) { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] On | iSwitch }
}
on *:TEXT:*:?: {
  if ($active == $nick) { halt }
  elseif (%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$nick) ] ] !== On) { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$nick) ] ] On | iSwitch }
}
on *:ACTION:*:#: {
  if ($active == $chan) { halt }
  elseif (%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] !== On) { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] On | iSwitch }
}
on *:ACTION:*:?: {
  if ($active == $nick) { halt }
  elseif (%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$nick) ] ] !== Yes) { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$nick) ] ] On | iSwitch }
}
on *:CONNECT: { iSwitch }
on *:DISCONNECT: { iSwitch }
on *:RAWMODE: {
  if ($active == $chan) { halt }
  elseif (%New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] !== On) { set %New [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] On | -Switch }
}
on *:OPEN:?: { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$nick) ] ] On | iSwitch }
on *:OPEN:#: { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$chan) ] ] On | iSwitch }

alias DCX_switch {
  if ($2 = mouse) { halt }
  var %command = $2
  tokenize 32 $4-
  if (%command = sclick) {
    set %target $remove($xdid(switchbar,1).seltext,$chr(40),$chr(41))
    if (@* iswm %target) { window -a $window($2) | halt }
    If (~* iswm %target) { window -a %target }
    scon $1
    if ($2 == 1) && (!$3) { list }
    elseif (#* iswm %target) { window -a %target }
    elseif ($query($3)) { window -a $query($3) }
    elseif (!$2) { window -a "Status Window" }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error appears when `ACTIVE` is being fired.

```
on *:ACTIVE:*: { set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$active) ] ] Off | iSwitch }
```

This happens because `$active` is set with a space when the focused window is the **Status Window**.

Which results: `%New.IRC.FoobarServer.comStatus Window Off`

A possible fix could **replace** the **space** with **underscore**(`_`)

```
set %New. [ $+ [ $+($server,$replace($active, $chr(32), _)) ] ] Off
```